# I m using create block theme plugin how to make a multi page theme and specific posts to a specific page

Tags: wordpress

suppose I generate a theme using create block theme plugin how to make it multi page theme by adding pages in the site editor and after that what to do if we need to add specific post to specific page in the theme

I  want someone to guide me into to wordpress block theme